# How to make and train a Model which read data after extracting pdf

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, spacy, pdf-extraction

Here i share my code

> main.py

```
from fitz import fitz
import spacy


location = "D:\python\Resume-Sample.pdf"
text = ''

with fitz.open(str(location)) as doc:
    for page in doc:
        text+=page.get_text("block")

    NER = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text1 = NER(text)
for word in text1.ents:
    print(word.text, word.label_)
```

> Result

:Abdul Moeez :E-mail- amoeez14@gmail.com : Phone +1111111111 : Address Karachi, Sindh, Pakistan

How i make and train a model so it recognizes Name Email Phone Address

Comment: You might find the spaCy course helpful. https://course.spacy.io/en/

Answer (score 0):

you need to go with spacy with proper guidance visit the link below for more details
https://spacy.io/universe/category/training/

the process using regex with pyperclip library
https://medium.com/@branzoldecode/phone-number-and-email-extractor-with-python-c88f88b42a8a

```
import re 
import pyperclip 
Alltext = pyperclip.paste() 
EmailRegex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0–9_.+]+@[a-zA-Z0–9_.+]+',re.VERBOSE) 
result = EmailRegex.findall(Alltext) 
pyperclip.copy(result)
```

this is just an example to find the specified things, but you need to implement you own logic to read the file first.